# @Value does not receives value

Tags: spring-boot

I try to start telegram bot, but when I start the application I get this:

```
org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException: Bot token and username can't be empty
```

I want to set this velues using org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value but it doesn't work

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.coffeOrderBot</groupId>
    <artifactId>CoffeBot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CoffeeBot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <telegram.version>5.6.0</telegram.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.telegram/telegrambots -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>${telegram.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CoffeeBotApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CoffeeBotApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    private final static BotConfig CONFIG = new BotConfig();
/// Some code
```

@Component
public class BotInitializer {

```
@Autowired
private Bot bot;

@EventListener({ContextRefreshedEvent.class})
public void init() throws TelegramApiException {
    TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
    try {
        telegramBotsApi.registerBot(bot);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
@Configuration
@Data
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class BotConfig {

    @Value("${bot.name}")
    String name;

    @Value("${bot.token}")
    String token;
}
```

I tryed to write:
@PropertySource(value = "application.properties")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")

Comment: If I set this values clearly - it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing `new BotConfig()`, which creates a plain instance without the Spring Framework knowing about the instance. Without knowing about the instance, the Spring Framework cannot populate the fields.

You must let Spring wire a `BotConfig` bean from the application context into the components which require it:

```
@Component
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    private final BotConfig config;

    @Autowired
    public Bot(final BotConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}
```

(The `@Autowired` annotation is optional if your class only has a single public constructor.)

Documentation: [Spring Framework / Core Technologies / The IoC Container / Dependencies / Dependency Injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/dependencies/factory-collaborators.html)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the values for the bot name and token are not being properly loaded from the **application.properties** file using the `@PropertySource`. The property names in your **application.properties** file should match the field names in your BotConfig class exactly. Then the BotConfig class should have exactly the same field names.

**application.properties**:

```
bot.name=your_bot_name
bot.token=your_bot_token
```

**BotConfig**:

```
@Data
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class BotConfig {
    @Value("${bot.name}")
    String name;

    @Value("${bot.token}")
    String token;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If `application.properties` is on the classpath which is in the default `src/main/resources` directory, Spring Boot will detect it automatically.
There is no need to explicitly register a `PropertySource`.

If you want to read values of `@Value` fields elsewhere, you can register these `@Value` fields as beans in the same config class.

The code would look like this:

```
@Configuration
public class BotConfig {

    @Value("${bot.name}")
    String name;

    @Value("${bot.token}")
    String token;

    @Bean(name = "botName")
    public String getBotName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Bean(name = "botToken")
    public String getBotToken() {
        return token;
    }
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    private final String botName;
    private final String botToken;
```

Finally, make sure that you have properties defined in `application.properties`.

```
bot.name=<BOT_NAME>
bot.token=<BOT_TOKEN>
```

Comment: I sure about fields in propeties, and I noticed warning: "Unused property". Thanx for @PropertySource by default I will know